# Где можно найти список всех макросов доступных в MSVC++ 2010 EXPRESS?

Tags: visual-c++, c++

На msdn находил только пару десятков и то в разных разделах, а остальные не знаю где искать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В каталоге, где у Вас установлена студия, находите папку include (она может быть вложенной). Дальше берете любимый редактор текста, который может искать по файлам в каталоге и ищете вхождение `#define`. У меня нашло более 6 тысяч. Понятное дело, что их нужно будет отдельно проанализировать, так как некоторые будут доступны только при определенных условиях.

Comment: жестоко)))

Comment: я сильно сомневаюсь, что где то есть полный список.

Comment: мне кажется он имел ввиду макросы самой студии а не языка